# How to Change LONG to CLOB in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, clob

How can I Change LONG datatype to CLOB in Oracle with function?

```
ALTER TABLE "TABLE_NAME"
ADD "CLOB_NAME" CLOB;

UPDATE "TABLE_NAME"
SET "CLOB_NAME" = TO_CLOB("LONG_NAME");

ALTER TABLE "TABLE_NAME"
DROP CLOUMN "LONG_NAME";

ALTER TABLE "TABLE_NAME"
RENAME CLOUMN "CLOB_NAME" TO "LONG_NAME";
```

I don't wanna use that code because I can't change the table element and doesn't have any permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to just alter table.

Here's an example:

Table with `long` datatype column:

```
SQL> create table test (col long);

Table created.
```

Let's populate it:

```
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select text from all_views
  3                  where text_length < 30000
  4                    and text is not null
  5                 )
  6    loop
  7      insert into test (col) values (cur_r.text);
  8    end loop;
  9  end;
 10  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

How many rows does it contain?

```
SQL> select count(*) from test;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        45
```

Just an excerpt:

```
SQL> select * from test where rownum = 1;

COL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT  q_name QUEUE, qt.msgid MSG_ID, corrid CORR_ID,  priority MSG_PRIORITY,
```

OK; now, **alter table** and modify `long` to `clob`:

```
SQL> alter table test modify col clob;

Table altered.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from test where rownum = 1;

COL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT  q_name QUEUE, qt.msgid MSG_ID, corrid CORR_ID,  priority MSG_PRIORITY,

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks for sharing answer but I have large table and I can't change or alter any column. I have to change on that column.

Comment: Regarding what you said so far, how do you plan to do it, then, if you can't ALTER anything and don't have any permission? From my point of view, you're looking for an impossible solution.