PL SQL export data
I'm using Oracle DB and I'm trying to map part of my schema.
I'm using the following query to recieve all views existing in my schema for further analysis:
select * from all_views where owner like '%SCHEMA_NAME%'

The result shows all views' data including the views' scripts.
Since the views' script can be very long - I cna't export the results for further analysis.
The data type of the column that shows the script is  and when trying to export it the result is truncated and I don't see the FULL view's script.
Any suggestion how to export the whole result set? Maybe if it's a memory issue, the solution would be to iterate the result set and export it one by one?

Instead of using the ALL_VIEWS data dictionary view, you could use the API DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL to get the view definition.

This is a problem with your client software that you're using to do the export, not with the Oracle database. Many clients are perfectly capable of dealing with the long datatype. Very likely your client has some configuration/settings screen where you can tell it how to deal with LOBs and longs.

This looks like having issues with column TEXT that is of LONG datatype. Detailed instructions and code to convert LONG datatype into CLOB "on-the-fly" could be found at: https://ellebaek.wordpress.com/2010/12/06/converting-a-long-column-to-a-clob-on-the-fly/

There is also LittleFoot's accepted answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75977379/how-to-change-long-to-clob-in-oracle
